# Django - Manual form field rendering adding a class

Tags: javascript, django, templates, django-templates

I am working with Google Re-Captcha and would like to enable the submit button once the Re-Captcha have been filled.
I want to add a callback function to the Div class my code looks something like this:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    {{ form.captcha.errors }}
       <div data-callback="enableBtn"></div>
    {{ form.captcha }}
 </div>
```

This currently returns the data-callback outside of the form.captcha. How can I add the data-callback attribute to the form.captcha?

So for ex:
If form.captcha is

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="== xxxxxx =="></div>
```

Instead of having

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="== xxxxxx ==" data-callback="enableBtn">
```

I have

```
<div data-callback="enableBtn">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="== xxxxxx =="></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by outside of the function ? Is that `enableBtn` function called ?

Comment: @RajaSimon My mistake, I meant outside of the form.captcha! I'll update to explain further

Comment: @RajaSimon I want to enable the submit button after the Re-Captcha have been completed. So once it is completed the enableBtn function get's called

Comment: Are you using this https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha ?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/ImaginaryLandscape/django-nocaptcha-recaptcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify widget url...

```
NORECAPTCHA_WIDGET_TEMPLATE (string) = location for the widget template.
```

Please refer this [html](https://github.com/ImaginaryLandscape/django-nocaptcha-recaptcha/blob/master/nocaptcha_recaptcha/templates/nocaptcha_recaptcha/widget.html) and make it like one and placed in your template and point it.